# How can I solve $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{xy\sin(x+y)}{x^2+y^2+|xy|}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

How can I solve:
$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{xy\sin(x+y)}{x^2+y^2+|xy|}$$
I used Wolfram Alpha, but it said that it doesn’t exist.

If I do it by myself I get:

$$0 < \left|\frac{xy\sin(x+y)}{x^2+y^2+|xy|}\right|<|xy\sin(x+y)| < |xy|,$$

so the limit exists and is 0, .. but how so, that it doesn’t exist? where may be my error?

Comment: I think your estimate is wrong for $x, y$ close to zero.

Comment: yeah, i suppose it because of that i am asking here.. help

Comment: Have you tried to use polar coordinates?

Comment: yes, and... $\lim_{ \rho \rightarrow 0} \frac{\rho ^2cos(\theta)sin(\theta)\sin(\rho(cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)))}{\rho ^2(1+|\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)|)}=\lim_{ \rho \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos(\theta)sin(\theta)\sin(0)}{1+|\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)|}=0$

Comment: The limit is $0$, what software says doesn't matter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your *argument* is not correct because the estimate
$$
\bigl|\frac{xy\sin(x+y)}{x^2+y^2+|xy|} \bigr|<|xy\sin(x+y)|
$$
is valid only if the denominator is greater than one,
and that is not the case for $x, y$ close to zero.

But your *result* is correct, the limit is indeed zero:
From
$$
\frac {|xy|}{x^2 + y^2 + |xy|} \le 1 \tag 1
$$
it follows that 
$$
\bigl| \frac{xy\sin(x+y)}{x^2+y^2+|xy|} \bigr| \le \ |\sin(x+y)|
\le  |x + y|
$$
which tends to zero for $(x, y) \to (0,0)$.

*Remark:* From the AM-GM inequality you have  $|xy| \le \frac{x^2 + y^2}2$ and
therefore the inequality $(1)$ can be improved to
$$
\frac {|xy|}{x^2 + y^2 + |xy|} \le \frac{|xy|}{2 |xy| + |xy|} = \frac 13 \, .
$$
But since the other factor $\sin(x+y)$ tends to zero, this better
estimate is not needed to compute the limit.